# X Axis label rounding not Rounding even if multiline option is selected

Tags: activex, teechart

I have selected multiline option in GetBottomAxis(), Since the text length of Bottom axis is large, So when I do a Save Image of Size 300x300 most of the area is taken by labels on X-Axis and chart displayed is small, Please let me know how I can roundoff the text of X-Axis Label.

Please Find the sample example,simply plotted a chart and extended the text length of X-Axis and exported the file by changing the size to 300x300 and below is the result.

[image]

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so we can reproduce the exact situation here

Comment: Have updated the question with the example hope this helps

Comment: An image is helpful (and I'll try to give an answer) but note a project is usually required to reproduce a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/activex/tutorials/index.html) to understand what's the purpose of that property:

```
**MultiLine labels**
Axis labels can be displayed as multi-line text instead of a single line of text. Lines are separated using the carriage-return ascii character ( #13 ).

*Example* 
    //Add the Series labels in this way and apply 'Marks' as Axis labelling style
    TChart1.Series(0).Add 1234, "New"+chr$(13)+"cars", vbRed
    TChart1.Series(0).Add 2000, "Old"+chr$(13)+"bicycles", vbBlue
```

If you have a very long text to be split, you should do it yourself.